# How to Pivot a Table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot, unpivot

My table has this structure

```
subcode date        rol1   rol2 rol3 rol4 rol5 rol6 upto rol60
--------------------------------------------------------------
mc1603  12/03/2011  p      p    a    p    p    p         a
mc1604  12/03/2011  p      p    a    p    p    p         a            
mc1605  12/03/2011  p      p    a    p    p    p         a
mc1606  12/03/2011  p      p    a    p    p    p         a
```

here

```
p=present   
a=absent
```

this table will be change into

```
rollno   mc1603 mc1604  mc1605 mc1606 date 
-------------------------------------------------
rol1     p      p       p      p      12/03/2011
rol2     p      p       p      p      12/03/2011
rol3     p      p       a      p      12/03/2011
```

Comment: My "dynamic pivot"-sense is acting up

Comment: This can't be done, because you cannot know which date to use. The date in the transposed table belongs to the rollno while the original date belongs to the subcode.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you would do this with both an `unpivot` and then `pivot`:

**Static query:**

```
create table #temp
(
    subcode varchar(50),
    date    smalldatetime,
    rol1    varchar(1),
    rol2    varchar(1),
    rol3    varchar(1),
    rol4    varchar(1),
    rol5    varchar(1),
    rol6    varchar(1),
    rol60   varchar(1)
)

insert into #temp values('mc1603', '03/12/2011', 'p', 'p', 'a', 'p', 'p', 'p', 'a')
insert into #temp values('mc1604', '03/12/2011', 'p', 'p', 'a', 'p', 'p', 'p', 'a')
insert into #temp values('mc1605', '03/12/2011', 'p', 'p', 'a', 'p', 'p', 'p', 'a')
insert into #temp values('mc1606', '03/12/2011', 'p', 'p', 'a', 'p', 'p', 'p', 'a')

SELECT p.rollNo, p.[mc1603], p.[mc1604], p.[mc1605], p.[mc1606], p.date
FROM
(
    SELECT *
    FROM
    (
        select subcode, date, rol1, rol2, rol3, rol4, rol5, rol6, rol60
        from #temp
    ) x
    UNPIVOT
    (
        presence FOR rollNo IN([rol1], [rol2], [rol3], [rol4], [rol5], [rol6], [rol60])
    ) unpiv
) x
PIVOT
(
    max(presence)
    FOR subcode IN([mc1603], [mc1604], [mc1605], [mc1606])
) p

drop table #temp
```

You can also do this with [Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html) but you will need to get the list of columns first before you can `unpivot` and then `pivot`:

**Dynamic query:**

```
-- get your roll no columns
DECLARE @cols AS VARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS VARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(c.Name) 
            FROM sys.columns c
            WHERE OBJECT_ID = OBJECT_ID('dbo.temp') AND c.NAME LIKE 'rol%'
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

-- get your dynamic string
set @query = 'SELECT p.rollNo, p.[mc1603], p.[mc1604], p.[mc1605], p.[mc1606], p.date
        FROM
        (
            SELECT *
            FROM
            (
                select subcode, date, ' + @cols + ' 
                from temp
            ) x
            UNPIVOT
            (
                presence FOR rollNo IN(' + @cols + ')
            ) unpiv 
        ) x
        PIVOT
        (
            max(presence)
            FOR subcode IN([mc1603], [mc1604], [mc1605], [mc1606])
        ) p'

exec(@query)
```

**Results:**

```
rol1    p   p   p   p   2011-03-12 00:00:00
rol2    p   p   p   p   2011-03-12 00:00:00
rol3    a   a   a   a   2011-03-12 00:00:00
rol4    p   p   p   p   2011-03-12 00:00:00
rol5    p   p   p   p   2011-03-12 00:00:00
rol6    p   p   p   p   2011-03-12 00:00:00
rol60   a   a   a   a   2011-03-12 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done, it's called a table transpose. On SQL Server it requires building a  dynamic SQL statement and executing it using the EXEC statement.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pivot the subcode column, and then unpivot the other roll columns.

The pivoted table would be a derived table inside the unpivot statement.

```
select * from
( 
SELECT * FROM () Table0 PIVOT () Table1
) Table2
UNPIVOT () Table3
```